# EntityType Field with Array Type

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to make a new form with EntityType with an array type in my entity but it's doesn't works.

In my entity:

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="array")
 */
private $category;
```

And in my form file:

```
->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
 'class' => 'PlatformBundle:Question',
 'choices' => 'category',
 'multiple' => true,
 'expanded' => true,
    ))
```

And i got this error:

> The option "choices" with value "category" is expected to be of type
>   "null" or "array" or "\Traversable", but is of type "string".

And in my database there is something like that:

> a:7:{i:0;s:3:"ADC";i:1;s:7:"Support";i:2;s:6:"Middle";i:3;s:6:"Jungle";i:4;s:3:"Top";i:5;s:6:"Leader";i:6;s:8:"Streamer";}

Category is a DC2Type:array

Do you know what is missing?

Thanks for your help
Hansen

Comment: the data saved in data base its normal its an array serialize .array (
  0 => 'ADC',
  1 => 'Support',
  2 => 'Middle',
  3 => 'Jungle',
  4 => 'Top',
  5 => 'Leader',
  6 => 'Streamer',
)

Answer (score 0):

For the 'choices' u're not allowed to set an String.
I think u look for something like this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities